# CSS, mouse off?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm in the middle of making a site that will showcase my graphic work. For one of the thumbnails of my work i've got it to do this

```
.example1:not:hover {
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
-moz-transition: all .15s linear;
transform:rotate(-7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
transition: transform 0.25s linear;
}
```

now, i want it to do

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
```

when you take your mouse of the thumbnail
The html of the thumbnail is

```
<div id ="maintext">    
<img src="Images/example.png" class="example1" >
</div>
```

thanks all.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for this, i tried .example1:not:hover { which didnt work, basically i want it on hover to tilt 7 degrees, and then when you take your mouse off to rotate -7 degrees.

Comment: so, it starts at `rotate:0`, then when you hover, you want `rotate:-7deg`, and then when off hover, you want `rotate:7deg`. Is that right. If that's what you're asking, then the answer is no, you can't; not with pure CSS; you'll need some Javascript in the mix.

Comment: ah okay, dont suppose you know how?

Comment: `.foo:not:hover` is quite absurd, because that’s `.foo` again. So apply transitions to _both_ of those “states”, `.foo` and `.foo:hover`

Comment: You'll also want to add `transition` for `-webkit-transform` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no explicit property for mouse leave in CSS. Now I understood what you want.

jQuery

```
$('.example1').on('mouseleave', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('mouseenter');
    $this.addClass('mouseleave');
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $this.removeClass('mouseleave');
    }, 150);
}).on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('mouseenter');
});
```

CSS

```
.example1 {
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: transform .15s linear;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.example1.mouseenter {
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
.example1.mouseleave {
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
}
```

Live Example:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinizinmoraes/eQSjC/5/)

Comment: Sorry, i'm very in-experienced when it comes to use jQuery, how would i implement this?

Comment: I will create a fiddle with a example 2 minutes

Comment: You are right, there is no _explicit_ property, but you don't need one.

Comment: I add a example take a look and see if this is waht you wanna accomplish, first start normal image, then on hover 7 deg when leave -7 deg and if hover again go to 7 deg

Comment: Okay it works but after i take my mouse off, it says at -7 rotate

Comment: It should get back to 0deg ?

Comment: it should, but it doesnt.<div id ="maintext">

 <img src="Images/example.png" class="example1" >
 <script>
$('.example1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).addClass('mouseleave');
});
</script>
    </div>

Comment: but now it doesnt go turn the oposite way on mouse off?

Comment: Dude you need to decide what you want, if you want he go -7deg when you mouse off why you ask he go to 0deg again ?

Comment: okay.
Image 0 degrees when nothing on/off
Mouse on - Rotate 7 deg
Mouse off - Rotate -7 deg then go back to the 0 degrees

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't use the `:not` selector like that.

If you want to specify something that is *not* hovered, you don't need any pseudoclass. I think you want something like this:

```
.example1 {
    /* no rotation */
}
.example1:hover {
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
```

Then, if you want a different state *after* it has been hovered, you'll need to add a class with javascript:

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".example1", function() {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
});
```

Now you can have a CSS class like this:

```
.example1.hovered {
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
}
```

Comment: this works, but doesnt go back to 0 degrees after the mouse has left :(

Answer (score 1):

Put what you want for the *non-hover* state in just `.example1 { ... }`. Then put the hover state in `.example1:hover { ... }`. So, if you want to make images rotated when not hovering, do it like this:

```
.example1 {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
  transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s linear;
}
.example1:hover {
  /* set all transforms to none or whatever you want when hovering */
}
```

Comment: let me explain, so, it starts at rotate:0, then when you hover, you want rotate:-7deg, and then when off hover, you want rotate:7deg. Is that right. If that's what you're asking, then the answer is no, you can't; not with pure CSS; you'll need some Javascript in the mix. is basically it, as spudley said.